# unable to find ImageView from the inflated layout

Tags: java, android, layout-inflater, android-inflate

I've created a layout and I am trying to binding to its IDs.

I have managed to bind to the `TextView`'s but I was unable to find imageView id for some reason.

```
 public FeedsAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull List objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.myFeeds = objects;
        this.activity = context;
        this.layoutId = resource;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.activity);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(this.layoutId, parent, false);
        Feed currentFeed = this.myFeeds.get(position);

        TextView authorTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.author);
        TextView dateTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        TextView contentTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.content);

        ImageView imgImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img);

        authorTextView.setText(currentFeed.getAuthor());
        dateTextView.setText(currentFeed.getDate());
        contentTextView.setText(currentFeed.getContent());
        return convertView;
    }
```

`ImageView imgImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img);`

this line return me an error that he doesn't know what is `R.id.img`

the is the layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/author"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.014"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.033" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.045"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.138" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.099"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.845" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="118dp"
        android:layout_height="106dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.091"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/a150" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

btw, I'm looking for an option to put a placeholder for the imageView without put any `src` is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: For placeholder  use Picasso library

Comment: is it possible that you inflate the wrong layout?

Comment: @MartinFrank, No, i have add the constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this error on android studio 3.6,but you can compile your code without any failing!
close android studio and reopen it, Your error must be fixed, right?!

Answer (score 1):

This can happen sometimes when the cache in the editor gets out of sync with the resources file. The best way to fix this is by going to File > Invalidate Caches/Restart